# Count multiple point layers in polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to count different stores inside trade zone polygons in a sql-query. Each store is a different table in my postgis database.

It is possible to count points in polygons using the following code taken from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54680/19349:

```
SELECT grid.gid, count(kioskdhd3.geom) AS totale 
FROM grid LEFT JOIN kioskdhd3 
ON st_contains(grid.geom,kioskdhd3.geom) 
GROUP BY grid.gid;
```

I modified the code to allow for multiple points:

```
SELECT grid.gid, 
count(DISTINCT store1.geom) AS store1_count,
count(DISTINCT store2.geom) AS  store2_count
FROM grid
LEFT JOIN store1
ON st_contains(grid.geom,store1.geom)
LEFT JOIN store2
ON st_contains(grid.geom,store2.geom) 
GROUP BY grid.gid;
```

This worked, but surely there needs to be a better way, as continuous left joins will exponentially worsen the execution time.

Comment: no, your DB design is limiting this sort of operation to cross-table joins or unions. if your DB is not subject to any design imperatives, it's generally an anti-pattern in RDBS design to physically split homogeneous data into *attribute* tables; rather, key columns, indexes and maybe partitioning are the tools of choice here, e.g. having a primary data table and [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) supplements.

Comment: @ThingumaBob. Thanks for the reply. I was hoping to have all my queries in one place, but I guess I'll stick to calling python or R scripts for this kind of spatial aggregation. Will also take a look at some of the tools you mentioned.

Comment: Note that those 'tools' are common DB concepts/functionalities. The design I was referring to is to have *one* table for *all* your points, with e.g. a `PRIMARY KEY` column referencing the 'store id' (possibly in another, smaller table storing individual data for each 'store'). This way you can query *one* table, powered by indexes (a spatial index on your geom column is mandatory).